# How to use a background image in sculpting mode?

Tags: image, workflow, sculpting

I know that you can use a background image in layout mode(?) with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then do the modelling there (by setting the opacity lower and so on ..)

I was wondering if I could do a similar thing when sculpting so that I can sculpt the proportions 'better' by using the image ? I couldn't find a guide on the internet for this so here I am.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the camera properties and choose the image background images option.

[image]

Comment: hmm i tried doing so, here are my results: [imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/cmvqGwp) 
it shows the image when in camera view (numpad 0), but if i rotate the scene it doesn't anymore. is it meant to work like this ?